# JAXB java class generation from schema: how to get a custom XML element name (keep class name)

Tags: java, jaxb, xml-namespaces, jaxb2-maven-plugin, schemagen

I have an XSD with an element - it is the XMLRootElement if that makes a difference - like this:

`<xsd:element name= "SomeElement">`

I need to have the generated Java class have a custom XML element name while keeping the default Java class name, so the generated class needs to look like this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "fo:SomeElement")
public class SomeElement
```

So that marshal/unmarshalled xml elements will show as

`<fo:SomeElement>`

Can someone help me out with what I need to change to either the XSD file or the binding file?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, with your question you opened a big can of worms.
Things are more complicated than you thought they would be.
To fully understand the rest of this answer
you will surely need to learn more about the namespace concept in XML,
for example at [w3schools.com - XML Namespaces](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_namespaces.asp).
Having said that, the following stuff should give a quick entry into that topic.

Note that `fo:SomeElement` is not directly an XML element name.
The `fo:` is a so-called namespace-prefix.
The namespace-prefix needs to be mapped to a namespace-URI by `xmlns:fo="..."`,

By convention `fo:` is the namespace-prefix used for [XSL Formatting Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects).
Therefore most probably your XML file will look like this:

```
<fo:SomeElement xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format" ...>
    ...
</fo:SomeElement>
```

Note that `"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"` is the namespace-URI
as specified in the [XSL Formatting Objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL_Formatting_Objects) specification.

Note also, that namespace-prefixes (here `fo`) by themselves are irrelevant
and were only invented to make the XML content easier to read for humans.
So instead of `fo` you might as well have used `bla` in all places as the namespace-prefix,
and the XML content still would have the exact same meaning.
The only relevant things are the namespace-URIs (here `"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"`).

With JAXB the correct Java root class would look like this.
Note the `namespace` given in the [`@XmlRootElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlRootElement.html#namespace--) annotation.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="SomeElement", namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format")
public class SomeElement {
   ...
}
```

You would need to specify this namespace-URI not only in `@XmlRootElement`,
but also for nested Java properties corresponding to any `<fo:something>` XML content.
Fur this purpose most JAXB annotations ([`@XmlElement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElement.html#namespace--), [`@XmlAttribute`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAttribute.html#namespace--), ...)
can accept a `namespace` parameter as well.

The XML schema definition (XSD) consistent with the XML example and
the Java class above would look like this.
Note the `targetNamespace` given in the `<xs:schema>` element.

```
<xs:schema version="1.0" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format"
                         xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="SomeElement">
    ...
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```